# javascript fetch api and session timeout

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Is there a way to have a central place in code to handle the javascript's fetch api session timeout/errors?

I'm looking for something like:

```
addEventListenter('fetch', function (event) {
    if (event.response === 401) {
        console.log('*** session timeout');
    }
});
```

This code does not work BTW

Comment: No, there is not. Write a custom function that handles this, and call it in all places instead of `fetch` directly